# Geocoding? Adding coordinates column to a dataset of spots

Tags: geolocation, gis, google-geocoding-api

If I have a dataset with industries names and cities where they’re placed, is there a way I can get addresses or coordinates automatically from google maps?  I tried asking ChatGPt that told me to use Geoocoding.

I need to create a column in the dataset with the address or the coordinates so I can geolocate them on a map. I only have the cities column.

Example: Smaltimento Rifiuti Ecoiso | Napoli. I need two other columns with the coordinates taken from Google Maps or another with the address (better the first ones)

Tried getting Google apis

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your chances of getting help and please note that it is recommended that you do your own research first before asking a question. With that said, I'd suggest that you read through the Google Maps Geocoding API documentation to know more about the capabilities of the API. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding

Answer (score -1):

This code uses the Google Places API to fetch the address and `Geolocation` (latitude and longitude) for various industries in different cities. It iterates over a dataset containing industry names and cities, makes API requests to retrieve place IDs and details, and then logs the results with address and location information. The goal is to gather geographic data for each industry-city pair using the Google Places API

##### One Google API

You need to enable one Google API
[Places API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service)

[image]

You need to copy API Key from your project of Google account.

```
https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-resource-manager
```

[image]

More detail information in [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/get-started)

##### Demo code

This code will address your question.

Save as `get-address.js`

```js
const axios = require('axios');

const API_KEY = 'Your Google Maps API key';

// your data sat
const data = [
    { industry: 'Smaltimento Rifiuti Ecoiso', city: 'Napoli' },
    { industry: 'Automotive Manufacturing', city: 'Turin' },
    { industry: 'Fashion Design', city: 'Milan' },
    { industry: 'Wine Production', city: 'Florence' },
    { industry: 'Maritime Shipping', city: 'Genoa' },
    { industry: 'Tourism Hospitality', city: 'Venice' },
    { industry: 'Food Processing', city: 'Bologna' },
    { industry: 'Ceramics Production', city: 'Faenza' },
];

async function getPlaceDetails(placeId) {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json', {
            params: {
                place_id: placeId,
                key: API_KEY
            }
        });

        if (response.data.result) {
            const { formatted_address, geometry } = response.data.result;
            const { lat, lng } = geometry.location;
            return { address: formatted_address, location: { latitude: lat, longitude: lng } };
        } else {
            throw new Error('No details found for place ID: ' + placeId);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error('Error fetching place details: ' + error.message);
    }
}

async function searchPlaceId(cityName, industryName) {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json', {
            params: {
                query: industryName + ' in ' + cityName,
                key: API_KEY
            }
        });

        if (response.data.results.length > 0) {
            const placeId = response.data.results[0].place_id;
            return placeId;
        } else {
            throw new Error('No results found for query: ' + industryName + ' in ' + cityName);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error('Error fetching place ID: ' + error.message);
    }
}

async function getAddressAndLocationForIndustryAndCity(industryName, cityName) {
    try {
        const placeId = await searchPlaceId(cityName, industryName);
        const { address, location } = await getPlaceDetails(placeId);
        return { industry: industryName, city: cityName, address, location };
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error('Error getting address and location: ' + error.message);
    }
}

async function fetchData(data) {
    const results = [];
    for (const { industry, city } of data) {
        try {
            const result = await getAddressAndLocationForIndustryAndCity(industry, city);
            results.push(result);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(`Error processing ${industry}, ${city}: ${error.message}`);
        }
    }
    return results;
}

fetchData(data)
    .then(results => {
        console.log('Address and location for each industry:');
        console.log(results);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error:', error.message);
    });
```

##### Input data

```json
[
    { industry: 'Smaltimento Rifiuti Ecoiso', city: 'Napoli' },
    { industry: 'Automotive Manufacturing', city: 'Turin' },
    { industry: 'Fashion Design', city: 'Milan' },
    { industry: 'Wine Production', city: 'Florence' },
    { industry: 'Maritime Shipping', city: 'Genoa' },
    { industry: 'Tourism Hospitality', city: 'Venice' },
    { industry: 'Food Processing', city: 'Bologna' },
    { industry: 'Ceramics Production', city: 'Faenza' }
]
```

##### Output

```json
[
  {
    industry: 'Smaltimento Rifiuti Ecoiso',
    city: 'Napoli',
    address: "Cupa Vicinale Sant'Aniello, 96, 80146 Napoli NA, Italy",
    location: { latitude: 40.82747369999999, longitude: 14.3224339 }
  },
  {
    industry: 'Automotive Manufacturing',
    city: 'Turin',
    address: "S.da Comunale da Bertolla all'Abbadia di Stura, 132, 10156 Torino TO, Italy",
    location: { latitude: 45.1095563, longitude: 7.7345843 }
  },
  {
    industry: 'Fashion Design',
    city: 'Milan',
    address: 'Via Giuseppe Broggi, 7, 20129 Milano MI, Italy',
    location: { latitude: 45.4781573, longitude: 9.2103889 }
  },
  {
    industry: 'Wine Production',
    city: 'Florence',
    address: 'Via dei Pepi, 22, 50122 Firenze FI, Italy',
    location: { latitude: 43.77029899999999, longitude: 11.263162 }
  },
  {
    industry: 'Maritime Shipping',
    city: 'Genoa',
    address: 'Via Galeazzo Alessi, 1, 16128 Genova GE, Italy',
    location: { latitude: 44.4029039, longitude: 8.9384841 }
  },
  {
    industry: 'Tourism Hospitality',
    city: 'Venice',
    address: "Via degli Arditi, 35, 30013 Ca' Ballarin VE, Italy",
    location: { latitude: 45.4737973, longitude: 12.5279771 }
  },
  {
    industry: 'Food Processing',
    city: 'Bologna',
    address: 'Via Francesco Zanardi, 54, 40131 Bologna BO, Italy',
    location: { latitude: 44.5136966, longitude: 11.3258413 }
  },
  {
    industry: 'Ceramics Production',
    city: 'Faenza',
    address: 'Piazza 2 Giugno, 7/palazzo Muky, 48018 Faenza RA, Italy',
    location: { latitude: 44.2887423, longitude: 11.8772864 }
  }
]
```

##### Install node.js dependency

```
npm install axios
```

##### Run it

```
node get-address.js
```

Result
[image]